# Does a flexible date car rental price matrix tool exist?

Tags: car-rentals

I know there are comparison rental tools like Kayak and Expedia, but I'm specifically thinking of a tool similar to Google Flight's flexible date matrix, where they'll show you the lowest prices for a matrix of start and end dates.

I've found that with car rentals, the prices can change drastically just by booking a day earlier or later, or sometimes even just hours apart, to the tune of 50% a price reduction, and doing this all manually is pretty frustrating.

**To be clear**: I know there are existing price comparison tools, but I'm specifically asking about whether something similar to Google Flight's flexible date tool exists, where you can get a sense for price changes across multiple start/end dates and durations.